# Trying to undestand how to define a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this equation system:

[image]

Then, I can resolve using the inverse, like this:

```py
import numpy

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2]])
s = np.array([15, 21, 13])
A_i = np.linalg.inv(A)

r = np.dot(s, A_i)

print(r)

[5. 4. 2.]   # this is correct
```

However, when I use `print(np.linalg.solve(A, s))`, I obtain:

```py
[-29.   6.  38.]
```

Now, if I write matrix A as:

```
[[1 1 3]
 [1 2 4]
 [1 1 2]]
```

```py
A = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,2,4],[1,1,2]])

print(np.linalg.solve(A, s))
>>> array([5., 4., 2.])     # this is correct
```

I would like to understand why this discrepancy occurs and what is the correct way to define an `np.array()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Matrix multiplication is not commutative.* For the first problem, `[-29, 6, 38]` is the correct answer, but that is skipping over some important things.

Your `s` vector is, according to numpy, of shape `(3,)`, so numpy will make operations work when they shouldn't, which can be dangerous. If we defined `s = np.array([[15], [21], [13]])` (i.e. as a column vector) and try taking the dot product as `np.dot(s, A_i)`, we get an error, since the shapes are incompatible.

So, what is happening is in your first example is you actually solved the problem:

[image]

Notice how that is the transpose of your original problem. What you actually want to do is define `A` as you did in the second part.

```py
A = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,2,4],[1,1,2]])
print(A)

[[1 1 3]
 [1 2 4]
 [1 1 2]]
```

To make sure you're using the correct shapes, you then define `s` as the column vector I showed earlier, which has numpy shape `(3,1)`. Then you will have agreeing results between the dot product (when performed in the right order) of the inverse and the linear algebra solve function (which is what you should normally use for faster results).

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,2,4],[1,1,2]])
s = np.array([[15], [21], [13]])
A_i = np.linalg.inv(A)
r1 = np.dot(A_i, s)
r2 = np.linalg.solve(A, s)

print(np.all(r1 == r2))    # True
```